# How to allocate memory for a struct variable whose members are of type string

Tags: c++, memory-management

My struct:

```
struct Company {
    string name;
    string profit_tax;
    string address;
};
```

I allocated by using line:

```
Company* a = (Company*)calloc(m, sizeof(Company));
```

with `long long m =pow(10,9)+9`
but pointer a is a null pointer after allocating. I don't know why this happened?. Please tell me solution, thanks!

Comment: In 99% of the time, the solution would be `auto a = new Company[m];`

Comment: @StefanRiedel I disagree. Much better would be `std::vector<Company> a(m);`.

Comment: Size of `std::string` is something like 24 or 32 bytes on 64-bit architecture. Are you aware that you are allocating 72 or 96 GB? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: BTW, do you really want just to allocate memory (storage), or do you also want objects in this storage to be constructed?

Comment: @DanielLangr, I know it, my laptop has 8gb RAM. But  this is task of my exercise. I think it 
 is wrong

Comment: please include the exact requirement of the exercise. Unlikely `Company* a = (Company*)calloc(m, sizeof(Company));` with `long long m =pow(10,9)+9` is what you need to do. What you need to do instead is unclear

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes a vector would indeed be better. My comment was aimed at situations where you want manual memory management. But as it stands it just looks like bad advice.

Comment: @StefanRiedel Note that with `new` expression, you also don't have a _manual memory management_. `new` expression internally calls memory allocation function `operator new` for you automatically and you have no "manual control" over it. `std::vector` with a default allocator template argument effectively does the same.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yes but you can also argue that `malloc` isn't really manual memory management because it calls `sbrk` and stuff automatically for you. I would consider `new` and `delete` (and variants) "manual" enough to call it "manual memory management". Like "manual transmission" isn't pushing the gears by hand either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating way too much memory for your computer (unless you have a huge amount of memory).

See [this godbolt example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccmath%3E%0A%0Astruct+Company+%7B%0A++++std::string+name%3B%0A++++std::string+profit_tax%3B%0A++++std::string+address%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A++++auto+company_size+%3D+sizeof(Company)%3B%0A++++auto+target_size+%3D+std::pow(10,+9)+%2B+9%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22struct+Company+size+:+%22+%3C%3C+company_size+%3C%3C+%22+bytes%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Num+elements+:+%22+%3C%3C+target_size+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Total+bytes+needed+:+%22+%3C%3C+(company_size+*+target_size)+/+1e9+%3C%3C+%22+GB/n%22%3B%0A++++%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:58.32195140734734,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.331155972278154,l:%274%27,m:52.393461762988906,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:47.606538237011094,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:41.678048592652644,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), the computation shows that on their hardware you would be trying to allocate 96GB of memory!

If this is an exercise, maybe you have a typo somewhere on the size you have to allocate?
If not, you can try to replace the `std::string` to indexes/pointers to where the strings are stored. It should save some memory, but you'll still have issues. Otherwise you'll have to process the data differently, by processing it in chunks.

If you're using C++, why are you using `calloc`? You could simply have `std::vector<company> companies(m);` and that will allocate the memory AND construct all your objects. Less error-prone, and more readable.

Comment: I am learing about hash, so the task requires create hash table with size as I mentioned. I used new, then i you calloc but both are not successfull.

Comment: All will fail if you can't allocate the memory you asked for.

Comment: link my  exercise [link]https://drive.google.com/drive/recent

Comment: That link doesn't work. It would probably be better anyway that you modify your question with any relevant information you have.